# The function for Modular Exponentiation, what is wrong with my two lines of code?

Tags: python, cryptography

We are asked to add two lines of code to this function our professor gave us for Modular Exponentiation. I have run multiple test and end up with the wrong answer. I was wondering if the two lines of code I added make sense so here it is:

```py
def powmod(a,b,m):
    bin=binary(b) #List containing the digits of b in binary
    length = len(bin) #Number of digits in when b is written in binary
    product=1  # Use this to store the current product of terms
    for i in range(0,length):
        if bin[i]==1:
            # Insert ONE line of code here.
              product = product * a %m <----- INSERTED CODE
        #Insert ONE line of code here to square a and reduce it modulo m.
              a = a **2%m <----- INSERTED CODE
    return product
```

Input: `powmod(13,654321,2018)`
Output I get:  `1213`
Correct output: `1835`

Comment: use parentheses to make clear the order of evaluation you are trying to achieve. Also, indentation is of critical importance in python code. Think about how the squaring line should be indented.

Comment: Thank you I see your point! I finally figured it out thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the required result 1835?

```
def binary(b):
    digits=[]
    while b>0:
        if b%2==1:
            digits.append(1)
            b = b-1
        else:
            digits.append(0)
            b = b/2
    return digits
def powmod(a,b,m):
    bin=binary(b) #List containing the digits of b in binary
    length = len(bin) #Number of digits in when b is written in binary
    product=1  # Use this to store the current product of terms
    for i in range(0,length):
        if bin[i]==1:
            # Insert ONE line of code here.
              # product = product * a %
              pass #return a #does nothing if it enters this condition
        #Insert ONE line of code here to square a and reduce it modulo m.

        product = product * a % m
    return product

print powmod(13,654321,2018)

Output: 1835
```

Comment: I am getting 1169, I am using a site called Cocalc so idk if your using an ide for this or not

Comment: i'm using latex but okay so it might be cocalc then and I'll have to talk to my professor about it

Comment: Sure this is one way to do so I guess :)

Comment: Thank you for your help though!